# Should I maximally decomposite my tables in my relational database?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, decomposition

I have a postgres database with one table:

- id
- Device1_Value
- Device1_SomeAdditionalInfo
- Device2_Value
- Device2_SomeInfo
- Device3_Value

Should I decomposite it to three tables:

One:

- id
- Device1_Value
- Device1_SomeAdditionalInfo

Two:

- id
- Device2_Value
- Device2_SomeInfo

Three:

- id
- Device3_Value

Could you please answer *yes/no* and why?

Comment: My 2 cents: For starters, yes: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" (btw it's called "normalization"). Anyway, I think this question is opinion-based, so I'm flagging it as such :)

Comment: Oh - also: you'll need 4 tables for that - the fourth is (id, device1_id, device2_id, device3_id)

Comment: Does any objective arguments based on some standards exist to choose the best way decomposite/do nothing for this table?

Comment: There is some theoretic stuff (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms), but... personally I think that makes it more complicated than it really is. Just take your initial table and start replacing groups of columns with ids to new tables until you think you are done :)

Comment: @giorgiga I found that 6th normal form is about decomposition. However, in this normalization form wiki talks about some other stuff - decomposition  of relations. I can't find anything about decomposition for my stuff, therefore I ask my question here.

Comment: Look at the example in wikipedia: they don't replace the "Type" column with ids (which would be 3NF?), but they remove the column altogether, because "Type" is really determined by "Practice in years". Really this distinctions are as useful for learning db design as the touring machine is for learning javascript... :)

Comment: If you are *really* interested in the theoretic stuff, however, go on and pick up a good db book (buy the one they use at some uni you like) and/or watch uni classes on youtube: trying to grasp this stuff via wikipedia is more or less like trying to learn calculus through wikipedia (ie: possible, but not easy) - also, shut down your postgres server: you won't need it for the theory

Comment: I really interested in answer for my issue with professional opinion why I should composite/decomposite data. Book reading takes a lot of time, I will do it, however, I need an explanation for this simple stuff now, not through some month when I finished the reading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165196/discussion-between-pepeevich-and-giorgiga).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full normal form is sometimes not optimal for usage. It is a trade off between normal form and the requirements.

So, if the values of device2 and device3 are dependent on device1 (they are only generated if there is a value for device1), and they are not separately required in some application by queries (mean you only need all record at once), then its better to have a single table as it is.

On the other hand, values for each device are generated separately and not dependent upon each other, then you should have separate tables.

Comment: Does any difference exist between query to get data from two tables device1 and device2 or get all data from one table (includes device1 and device2 data)?

Comment: query is the same. but if records get huge then there is difference for performances and indexes

Comment: Am I right that get data for device1 from common table is slower than get  all data from device1 table?

Comment: if the number of records are huge, otherwise there should not be an observable difference

Comment: Thank you. I take a decision that I shouldn't decomposite the table.